# Using get() function

Tags: python

So I am creating a dictionary with the values given in a csv file and now I am trying to have an input where you type in a key and it will check the dictionary for that key and then return the value.  I am having trouble implementing this but this is what I have and I believe I should be using d.get() but I'm not 100 percent sure.

```
import csv

dictionary = []

line = 0
reader = csv.reader(open("all.csv", "rb"), delimiter = ",")

header = reader.next()

for column in reader:
    line = line + 1

    dictionary.append({column[0]:column[2]})

print dictionary

check = raw_input("Enter word in dictionary to get its value: ")

print dictionary.get(check, "This word doesnt exist in the dictionary")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dictionary = []
```

That is not a dictionary, it is a list. Thus, it doesn't have a `get` method.

What you want to do is initialize the dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {}
```

(Note the curly braces rather than the square brackets). Also change the assignment line to this:

```
    dictionary[column[0]] = column[2]
```

At that point, your program should work.

Comment: Ahh okay I see now, thjanks so much for clarifying